Abbreviation for variable that depends on another variable
I am new to lean, and I am just attempting to write basic math proofs "from scratch" (I mean without mathlib's definition of "field").
In the code below, is there a neat way to introduce an abbreviation for "F.add, F.a0, ..." so that I don't have to repeatedly write "F." in the axioms and theorems?
import Mathlib.Tactic.NthRewrite

variable {α : Type}

structure aField where
  add : α→α→α
  mul : α→α→α
  a0 : α
  a1 : α
  neg : α→α
  inv : α→α

variable {F : aField}
variable {x y z : α}

axiom f0 : F.add x F.a0 = x
axiom fneg : F.add (F.neg x) x = F.a0
axiom fdist : F.mul x (F.add y z) = F.add (F.mul x y) (F.mul x z)
axiom fassoc_a : F.add x (F.add y z) = F.add (F.add x y ) z
axiom fcomm_a : F.add x y = F.add y x

I tried def add := F.add but that doesn't work because F is not defined, it's just a variable name (I think).
Thank you in advance
EDIT
Following the suggestions, if I write
variable {α : Type}

class aField where
  add : α→α→α
  a0 : α

variable {F : aField}
variable {x : α}

open aField (add a0)

axiom f0 : add x a0 = x

I get an error
typeclass instance problem is stuck, it is often due to metavariables
  aField

According to the doc, the type of an input has not been provided. But both x and a0 are of type α. How should I fix this?
EDIT 2
This almost works, except for the line under the TODO comment:
variable {α : Type}

class aField (α) where
  add : α→α→α
  a0 : α

  f0 : add x a0 = x


open aField

variable [F: aField α]
variable {x y z : α}

theorem az : add x a0 = x := by

  /-TODO: if you change F.a0 to a0, you get error-/
  have h1 : add a0 a0 = F.a0 := f0
  sorry

Any suggestions?
EDIT 3
Bounded x, but still error
variable {α : Type}

class aField (α) where
  add : α→α→α
  a0 : α

  f0 : ∀ x, add x a0 = x


open aField

variable [F: aField α]
variable {x y z : α}

theorem az : add x a0 = x := by

  /-TODO: if you change F.a0 to a0, you get error-/
  have h1 : add a0 a0 = F.a0 := f0 a0
  sorry

EDIT 4
Finally, it works (following the suggestion of adding α := α)
import Mathlib.Tactic.NthRewrite

variable {α : Type}

class aField (α) where
  add : α→α→α
  mul : α→α→α
  a0 : α
  a1 : α
  neg : α→α
  inv : α→α

  f0 : add x a0 = x
  fneg : add (neg x) x = a0
  fassoc_a : add x (add y z) = add (add x y ) z
  fcomm_a : add x y = add y x
  fdist : mul x (add y z) = add (mul x y) (mul x z)


open aField

variable [F: aField α]
variable {x y z : α}
  
theorem cancel : add x y = add x z → y = z := by

  intro h1
  have h2 : add (neg x) (add x y) = add (neg x) (add x z) := by rw[h1]
  rw[fassoc_a, fassoc_a] at h2
  rw[fneg] at h2
  rw[fcomm_a] at h2
  nth_rewrite 2 [fcomm_a] at h2
  rw[f0, f0] at h2
  exact h2

theorem mul_a0 : mul x a0 = a0 := by

  have h : mul x a0 = mul x a0 := rfl
  have h1 : add (α := α) a0 a0 = a0 := f0
  nth_rewrite 1 [← h1] at h
  have h1: mul x (add a0 a0) = add (mul x a0) (mul x a0) := fdist
  nth_rewrite 1 [h1] at h
  have h1: add (mul x a0) a0 = mul x a0 := f0
  nth_rewrite 3 [← h1] at h
  exact cancel h


The best is via type classes.  This is why Fields and other similar classes of objects are expressed in Mathlib as type classes instead of just structures.

Also, you really probably don’t want to  use axiom for the field axioms.  Instead put them as part of the structure (or better, make the structure a type class).

As Jason Rute suggested, you'd be better off defining aField as a typeclass rather than just a structure, as that will allow you to ask Lean automatically figure out what is the field structure that should equip a certain type, in a given context.
For instance, in your example, the add function has name aField.add : {α : Type} → aField (α := α) → α → α → α.  You could make it available in the current namespace, by doing, for instance, open aField (add), but then, it would still be cumbersome to use, because you explicitly have to pass F around as an argument:
axiom f0 : add F x F.a0 = x`

If you made aField into a class:
class aField where
  add : α→α→α
  mul : α→α→α
  a0 : α
  a1 : α
  neg : α→α
  inv : α→α

the signature of aField.add would be {α : Type} → [aField (α := α)] → α → α → α.  The difference is that the F argument is now within brackets, which means that it is an implicit argument, for which Lean will perform instance lookup to synthesize it. Concretely, this means that you can now write (assuming you have open aField (add a0))
axiom f0 : add x a0 = x

however, this might still be a bit annoying to write, as you'd probably prefer to use some infix notation for addition.  If you're ok using the usual + notation, you can change aField to become
class aField extends Add α where
  mul : α→α→α
  a0 : α
  a1 : α
  neg : α→α
  inv : α→α

extends Add α means that aField should also contain fields from the Add α structure.  Since its definition is exactly
class Add α where
  add : α → α → α

you still have the aField.add field.  However, one advantage of doing so is that Lean is aware of the Add class, and will desugar a + b into Add.add a b.  So now, you can write
axiom f0 : x + a0 = x

Similarly, you can extend the Mul α class to have access to the a * b notation, and the Neg α class to have access to the -a notation.
You can also define your own notation for the multiplicative inverse:
postfix:72 "⁻¹ " => aField.inv


I got an error (see my edit). What do you suggest?

I thought about making an "instance" like in the docs, but I don't want to fix a type for α (since I am trying to prove facts about all field).

@Moe weirdly enough, I thought I answered your comment, but now my comment doesn't appear anymore, so maybe I just forgot to click on the "send" button... anyways, the error in the first edit was due to the fact that when you write F : aField, since you don't specify which α to use in aField, and since F is never used afterwards, and thus never constrained, Lean doesn't know that F is the instance it has to use to synthesize the arguments of add and a0.

As for the second edit, there is a binding issue: in your f0 field, you never bind x. If you read your code again, you might even wonder how is that accepted at all, since you mention a variable that is bound nowhere. Lean will automatically bind otherwise unbound variables implicitly, at the definition level. Here, this means that you actually defined aField : {α : Type} → {x : α} → Type. This is clearly not what you want. I would suggest disabling entirely this kind of auto binding, at least until you're aware of where and how it triggers to avoid surprises.

Also, pragmatically, to solve your problem, you need to replace f0 : add x a0 = x with f0 : ∀ x, add x a0 = x.

"I thought about making an "instance" like in the docs, but I don't want to fix a type for α (since I am trying to prove facts about all field)" I am not entirely sure what you mean by that, but a class T is exactly the same as a structure T, except that it allows Lean to automatically synthesize implicit arguments of type T using instance resolution.

I bounded x in f0, but I still get an error (see edit 3)

@Moe this new error you get is unrelated to the previous one. You get this one because, in the new theorem you are trying to prove, add a0 a0 = a0, there is no way for Lean to infer which α you are speaking of. Adding any type hint, ie. add (α := α) a0 a0 = a0 is enough to make Lean happy.
